# V-if in a bootsrap vue form

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to render different form elements (placeholder and submit action) in a bootstrap vue form. Here is the form:

```
<template>
<b-form-input
    v-if="input"
    placeholder="Name Your Swatch, Enter and Save Edit"
    @keypress="republishSwatch"
    v-model="value3"
    ref="value3"
    id="name"
    size="lg"
    type="text"
    class="search-bar"
/>
<b-form-input
    v-else
    placeholder="Name Your Swatch and Enter to Save"
    @keypress="publishSwatch"
    v-model="value3"
    size="lg"
    ref="value3"
    id="name"
    type="text"
    class="search-bar"
/>
</template>
```

This works, and the default form shows, collects the name etc and runs the  publishSwatch function. The other form I want to use when someone is editing the swatch and changing the colors/name, using either the setName or the republishSwatch function so need some kind of condition in there to get it to show instead of the default one. At this point the the Save Edit (id saveBtn) button is showing in the DOM (shows after clicking the edit button) so wondered if I could somehow use that as a reference in condition, as its not there normally. The condition there at the moment doesn't seem to do anything, the default form shows, which is what I want to start with.

Any tips welcome

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Because your 2 situations(`v-if`/`v-else`) are very different, you should duplicate your `b-form-input`, by this way, you give `v-if` to the 1st one and `v-else` to the other one.

```html
<template>
<b-form-input
    v-if=""
    placeholder="Name Your Swatch and Enter to Save"
    @keypress="publishSwatch"
/>
<b-form-input
    v-else
    placeholder="Name Your Swatch, Enter and Save Edit"
    @keypress="republishSwatch"
    v-model="value3"
    ref="value3"
    id="name"
    size="lg"
    type="text"
    class="search-bar"
/>
</template>
```

With simpler examples, i.e. only a the placeholder which changes, you could do that

```js
<template>
<b-form-input
    :placeholder="test ? placeholder1 : placeholder2"
/>
</template>

<script>
export new Vue({
    data() {
        return {
            test: true,
            placeholder1: 'hi',
            placeholder2: 'bye',
        };
    }
});
</script>
```

If you mutate `test`, the input placeholder will automatically change.

Comment: OK if i just use the simpler example, where does the rest of the form go? Thanks

Comment: OK I have got it showing the default form like this, what do I have to put in to show this when the edit button is clicked? Thanks <b-form-input
    v-if="input"
    placeholder="Name Your Swatch, Enter and Save Edit"
    @keypress="republishSwatch"
    v-model="value3"
    ref="value3"
    id="name"
    size="lg"
    type="text"
    class="search-bar"
/>
<b-form-input
    v-else
    placeholder="Name Your Swatch and Enter to Save"
    @keypress="publishSwatch"
    size="lg"
    ref="value3"
    id="name"
    type="text"
    class="search-bar"
/>
</template>

Comment: can the simpler example be used with placeholder and keypress to run different function? Tujhanks